# Why second button cannot switch to the first View in react native

Tags: react-native

I tried to create an app using react native and used the following code to switch between different views in ViewPagerAndroid:

```
  _onPressButton = (position) => {
    this.refs.viewPage.setPage(position);
  }



render() {
      return (
        <ViewPagerAndroid
          style={styles.viewPager}
          initialPage={0}
          ref="viewPage"
        >
          <View style={styles.pageStyle} key="1">
            <Text
              style={{ fontSize: 24 }}
            >
              Spring
            </Text>
            <Image
                source={{ uri: 'https://media.defense.gov/2016/Apr/06/2001512498/780/780/0/160406-F-PM645-019.jpg' }}
                style={{ width: 420, height: 230 }}
            />
            <Button
              onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this, 2)}
              title="Summer"
              color="#841584"
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.pageStyle} key="2">
            <Text
              style={{ fontSize: 24 }}
            >
              Summer
            </Text>
            <Image
                source={{ uri: 'https://i2.wp.com/gothe-extramile.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/kinkakuji002.png?resize=600%2C450&ssl=1' }}
                style={{ width: 420, height: 230 }}
            />
            <Button
              onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this, 1)}
              title="Spring"
              color="#841584"
            />
          </View>
        </ViewPagerAndroid>
    );
  }
```

I expected to switch from Spring to Summer and vice versa. However, the button in Summer cannot go back to Spring. Any comment would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Console `position` on your button press. To check your `onPress` working or not.

Comment: Thanks @Heisen-Berg. I console position and found it did work. This is the modified code:

Comment: _onPressButton = (position) => {
    console.log(position);
    this.refs.viewPage.setPage(position);
  }

Comment: When I pressed the Summer button in the Spring View, it switched to the Summer View and the console showed 2. However, when I went on to pressed the Spring button in the Summer View, it was not able to go back to the Spring View, although the console still showed 1, which indicated that the button work.

Comment: instead of 1,2 try to use 0,1.

Comment: Many thanks, @Heisen-Berg. Your hint reminded me of check a script in the react native website:

Comment: Many thanks, @Heisen-Berg. Your hint reminded me of checking a script in the react native website:

    <ViewPagerAndroid
      style={styles.viewPager}
      initialPage={0}>
      <View style={styles.pageStyle} key="1">
        <Text>First page</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.pageStyle} key="2">
        <Text>Second page</Text>
      </View>
    </ViewPagerAndroid>

What is the key prop in the two <View>s? I kept considering this prop as the indexes of <View>s.

Comment: By the way, the react native website said "It is also important that each child (of a <ViewPagerAndroid>) have a key prop." I just deleted the key props in my code and no error happened. Please share more about this 'key' prop. I appreciate any help.